# Run function for each specific instance of a newly created div?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create web page that dynamically adds a div container every time a button is clicked, which is working fine. If I click the button twice, two containers are created, one above the other. However, the issue is that I'm trying to append and modify content inside each specific container using a specific function.

In a way, I understand that I'm only trying to run a function for each specific "instance" of the click. For example, if I were to click the button once, a new box shows up, and "Hi" shows up inside the box half a second later. If I were to click the button again, another box shows up, and "Hi" appears inside that box half a second later - without affecting the first box. My code currently looks something like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var parentContainer = $("<div class = 'actualstatus'></div>");
    parentContainer.hide().appendTo("#wrapper").fadeIn(1500);

    function add(){
        $("#actualstatus").append("<p>Hi</p>");
    };
    setTimeout(add,500);
});
```

The issue right now is that I'm creating a div container called parentContainer with a class 'actualstatus', so ALL newly created divs will have the same class name. Thus, on every click, all parentContainers get a "Hi" added to them - even the old ones. Right now, I'm wondering how to either

1. somehow distinguish newly created div containers or
2. run functions for specific instances only. I've tried using the $(this) element to append the "Hi", but I'm not sure if it's possible, or if I'm using the correct jargon. Please help!

Comment: Note that since you're using classes, `$("#actualstatus")` should be `$(".actualstatus")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply reference the element you just created, which is `parentContainer`:

```
function add(){
    parentContainer.append("<p>Hi</p>");
}
```

Comment: And this makes it run for that particular instance only?

Comment: `parentContainer` is a reference to the element you just created, so yes. I mean, you are doing the same thing in `parentContainer.hide().appendTo("#wrapper").fadeIn(1500);`. It hides and fades in only the new element, not every element with that class, right?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution IMO would be to pass the new div to your function so that only that div gets targeted.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var parentContainer = $("<div class = 'actualstatus'></div>");
    parentContainer.hide().appendTo("#wrapper").fadeIn(1500);

    function add(newdiv){
        newdiv.append("<p>Hi</p>");
    };
    setTimeout(function(){add(parentContainer)},500);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/h64kyvgx/)**